# Is using an integral type for an primary key more efficient storage-wise?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

Here's what I mean. Suppose I have a table called `Names` that is simply a unique list of names,

```
      Names 
================
      name
================
    "Charlie" 
----------------
    "George"
----------------
    "Bernie"
----------------
```

and another table that references those names,

```
        OtherTable  
=========================
  ... |   name    | ....
=========================
  ... | "Charlie" | ....
-------------------------
  ... | "Charlie" | ....
-------------------------
  ... | "Charlie" | ....
-------------------------
```

Does the database engine store the actual names in the `OtherTable`? Or does it optimize by storing some hidden reference to them?

If not, that means I should add a column to `Names` like

```
id |   Names 
==================
1  |     name
==================
2  |   "Charlie" 
------------------
3  |   "George"
------------------
4  |   "Bernie"
------------------
```

and reference it like

```
        OtherTable  
=========================
  ... |  name_id | ....
=========================
  ... |    1     | ....
-------------------------
  ... |    1     | ....
-------------------------
  ... |    1     | ....
-------------------------
```

The additional column on the `Names` table, however, is unnecessary as a primary key since the `names`, being unique, could server just as well as a primary key (except it might be slightly less efficient to look up by `name` because string comparison is slower than integer comparison).

Isn't this a Catch-22 situation?

Comment: I think you're guilty of pre-mature nano-optimization.  The developers of relational databases have been smart about creating indexes.  You should make your schema reflect the problem you're trying to solve.  These kinds of concerns won't make the difference on your app's performance.  Problems are more likely to lie in missing or inappropriate indexes, badly written SQL, excessive network latency, etc.

Answer (score 6):

The functional and logical aspects should take precedence over (very) minor efficiency aspects.

A problem with linking over meaningful columns (as the `name` column) is that meaningful columns tend to be subject to changes. E.g. you might discover a typo in a name and want to change it. An identity column as PK, on the other hand, is meaningless in that sense that it has no other meaning than being an identifier used internally and usually not displayed to the user. Since nobody cares about its real value, nobody will want to change it.

Strings can be case sensitive or not, can have different lengths, different collations, different encodings and different types (varchar, nvarchar, char, nchar). An `int` is simple (an `int` is an `int` is an `int`).

---

If you are using the names table as a simple lookup table having no relation to other tables, i.e., if you just want to use it as a handy way of filling a textbox but don't need any referential integrity (no Foreign Key), then you could use it as Primary Key.

---

Btw.: the DB does not create any magical, hidden reference, but does exactly what you tell it to do.

Answer (score 1):

The database will store the actual data value in the table.  If the primary key of the lookup table is a string, that string will be stored potentially many times in `OtherTable`.

Depending on the nature of the data, using a synthetic integer primary key for the `Names` table may well be more space efficient.  But you may pay a price for that in doing extra work joining the two tables rather than just getting the `name` from `OtherTable`.  A synthetic key, on the other hand, makes updating a `name` value much easier when "Charlie" decides that he wants to be known as "Charles" now.  As with just about any architectural decision, you have to determine whether the trade-offs are worth it.

Answer (score 0):

The in "other" table the engine will store what you tell it to when you create the column (that would be a string). So yes, there's redundancy there.

In this particular scenario you are doing a form of data compression by replacing the strings with shorter references to the same data. Many general purpose compression algorithms do a similar thing.

This is a valid thing to do if you care about the space savings. This is a complicated trade-off with many pros and cons.

You are not missing any major aspect I think.